# Angular: Fix prod error for one module only

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am working with a team on angular application I am responsible for one module and I want to fix the `ng build --prod` error related to this module only.

How can I view/check the errors only produced by this module

Thank you.

**Update**:

The build process stop if there is errors before checking my module and I can't fix this errors because they are out of my responsibility. In other word I can't use `ng build --prod` to see the error of my module if there are error beforehead.

Comment: Why not run the `ng build --prod` yourself and get the error?

Comment: sorry I didn't clear my statement the problem with `ng build -- prod` is that it doesn't show you the error of all modules. So if there is an error in a module it doesn't continue until you fix this errors. In my case there are errors that are not related to my module that stop the process

Comment: Maybe try to delete other modules util you get your module compiled?

Comment: I have tough about that but it doesn't seems like the right solution. because I will be changing many things on the shared files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a clone of the project and reduce it so that you can see what's going on with your own module. Then run `ng build --prod` so that you can see the error, from there you should be able to fix it and push the solution to the original project.

Comment: I have accepted this solution because it have help me but normally there should be an other optimized solution.